# Integral of a function on the reference FEM element

Tags: integration, matlab, finite-element-method, python

Suppose I have a triangulation in 1D with $X_h^1$ being the linear finite element space. The affine map I am using is the following

$$r = x_i + \gamma (x_{i+1} - x_i).$$

Suppose I want to compute the following integral

$$\int_{0}^1 f dx$$

on the reference element, where $f$ is a trigonometric function. To do this I have to map the quadrature point to the reference element, right?

But how can I do this in practice? Do I have to compute the value of the function at $r$ with $\gamma$ being $0$ at $x_i$ and $1$ at $x_{i+1}$?

Here some code I have written to do this:

```
def func_ref(z, x, a, b):
    return np.power((np.cos(x[a]) - np.cos(x[a]) * (1 - z)+
    np.cos(x[b]) * z) * (x[b] - x[a]), 2)
```

which is the integrand $\left (f - \Pi_h^1 (f) \right )^2x$ with $f$ being just the cosine function and the interpolant being represented by the linear combination of the function $f$ and the two basis function. Then I simply call the integration function on the interval $[0,1]$.

Thank you.

Comment: The quadrature points for integrating over $[0,1]$ are presumably fixed by whatever rule you choose.  However you will need to evaluate the integrand $f$ at each such point, and this is where a mapping from the reference element to your (one-dimensional) triangulation comes into play.  Higher dimensions are handled similarly.

Comment: @hardmath Thank you for the answer. I added some details because your answer is not clear to me.

Comment: Typically the "reference element" is a box or a simplex, and happily in 1D these are the same thing.  So in practical terms one sets up maps *from* the reference element *to* each element of the triangulation/discretization.  The integrals involving basis functions, etc. over the discretized domain can then be evaluated by repeated integrations over the reference element (including a factor for the Jacoban/change of variables that depends on the mapping of each discretized element).

Comment: @hardmath Do you know of any textbook or note where I can actually see this in practice (the calculations by hand)? Thank you.

Comment: Let me think about it.  I see you asked basically this same thing on SciComp.SE and got already an answer there.

Comment: [A Gentle Introduction to the Finite Element Method](http://arturo.imati.cnr.it/~marini/didattica/Metodi-engl/Intro2FEM.pdf) by Francisco–Javier Sayas (2008) starts with the 2D discretization using linear triangles, which maps the reference element to domain elements by affine maps, and goes on to  introduce high-dimensional and/or smoother elements.

Comment: That author wrote that the one-dimensional case makes a good introduction to general features of the FEM, but he has "an inner feeling" that it loses too much "richness" in that overly simple setting.  He has a [revised version](http://www.math.udel.edu/~fjsayas/documents/anIntro2FEM_2015.pdf) dated 2015 in which the promised appendix sketching the one-dimensional case is included.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks, I will have a look!